# Add bits in all possible places

Tags: python

I have a list  and I want to make all lists possible by adding x 1s and 0s in all possible places.   For example,say x = 2 and

```
l=[0,1]
```

First we just place all possible lists of length 2 at the start giving `[0,0,0,1]`, `[0,1,0,1]`, `[1,0,0,1]`, `[1,1,0,1]`. Then we place 0 or 1 at the start and 0 or 1 at position 2 giving `[0,0,0,1]`, `[0,0,1,1]`,  `[1,0,0,1]`, `[1,0,1,1]`.

We would then do the same for every possible pair of positions in the list where two bits can be inserted.  There will of course be a lot of duplicates but I can remove those using `set`.

Another example, this time with x = 1

```
l=[1,1]
```

The complete output should be `[0,1,1], [1,0,1], [1,1,0], [1,1,1]`.

Is there a smart way to do this?

Comment: Can you please specify what `x` is meant to do to this array? It looks like its meant to multiply it but your example result says otherwise.

Comment: @Serdalis  x just says how many 1s or 0s you have to add.

Comment: Is there a specific reason have `x=2` and an array instead of just x=4?

Comment: @Serdalis We are inserting bits into a given list. So it makes a difference what `l` is.

Comment: Could you rephrase the wording of the first sentence? "x 1s and 0s" VS "1s or 0s" in the comment is ambiguous. Plus: in your example, `[1,0,0,1]` occurs twice. Is this intentional? You probably need to clarify what "in all possible places" means *exactly*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you could use something like this:

```
from itertools import product, combinations

def all_fill(source, num):
    output_len = len(source) + num
    for where in combinations(range(output_len), len(source)):
        # start with every possibility
        poss = [[0,1]] * output_len
        # impose the source list
        for w, s in zip(where, source):
            poss[w] = [s]
        # yield every remaining possibility
        for tup in product(*poss):
            yield tup
```

which gives

```
>>> set(all_fill([1,1], 1))
set([(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1)])
>>> set(all_fill([0,1], 2))
set([(1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 1),
(0, 1, 0, 1), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 1, 0),
(0, 1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1, 1), (0, 0, 0, 1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is [`itertools.product`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
import itertools
x = 2
l = [0, 1]
print list(itertools.product(l + [0, 1], repeat=len(l)+x))
```

Comment: I added another simpler example. Your code gives (0, 0, 0) for example with l = [1,1] and x= 1 which is not what I intended.

Answer (score 1):

```
# input
l=[1,1]
x=1

# create bit combinations that may be added to l
import itertools
combos = itertools.product([0,1], repeat=x)

# iterate through positions (k) and bit combinations (c) with
# a single generator expression. Might be more memory efficient
# if combos would only be generated directly here
set(tuple(l)[:k] + c + tuple(l)[k:] for c in combos for k in range(len(l)+1))

# returns
# set([(0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)])
```

Comment: This won't generate outputs like `(1, 0, 1, 0)`, where the insertions are on both sides, or more generally the cases where the insertions aren't contiguous.